# Python - Pandas Percentile distribution less than 80%

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I have the following dataframe, how can I create a new column that has the cities that represent 80% of all values? In this case they are 'a', 'b' and 'c'. The rest of the cities should have a label that is 'other'.

```
values = ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','d','d','d','e','e','f']
db = pd.DataFrame(values,columns = ['city'])

db['city'].value_counts(normalize=True)

a    0.32
b    0.24
c    0.20
d    0.12
e    0.08
f    0.04
```

Desired Output

```
db['city_freq'] = ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','other','other','other','other','other','other']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter all values with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with condition, get `index` values anf then compare original by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for replace values:

```
s = db['city'].value_counts(normalize=True).cumsum()

print (s)
a    0.32
b    0.56
c    0.76
d    0.88
e    0.96
f    1.00

print (s.index[s > 0.8])
Index(['d', 'e', 'f'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
db.loc[db['city'].isin(s.index[s > 0.8]), 'city'] = 'other'
print (db)
     city
0       a
1       a
2       a
3       a
4       a
5       a
6       a
7       a
8       b
9       b
10      b
11      b
12      b
13      b
14      c
15      c
16      c
17      c
18      c
19  other
20  other
21  other
22  other
23  other
24  other
```

Another solution with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by cumulative sums and then compare by threshold:

```
s = db['city'].value_counts(normalize=True).cumsum()

db.loc[db['city'].map(s) > 0.8, 'city'] = 'other'
```

**Details**:

```
print (db['city'].map(s))
0     0.32
1     0.32
2     0.32
3     0.32
4     0.32
5     0.32
6     0.32
7     0.32
8     0.56
9     0.56
10    0.56
11    0.56
12    0.56
13    0.56
14    0.76
15    0.76
16    0.76
17    0.76
18    0.76
19    0.88
20    0.88
21    0.88
22    0.96
23    0.96
24    1.00
Name: city, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @gnodab - value_counts sorting be default, so not necessary.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for the info!